# How to vertical align header and link?

Tags: css, github

I'm using github's [Primer CSS](http://primercss.io/) framework and I'd like to have a `href` with the `class='btn'` and a `<h3>` in the same line with vertical alignment.

I could try to hack this but before I do I'd like to know if there's a recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to hack anything. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/8cox36as/1/). This is just a simple case of using Floats to put the two elements on the same line. Being that you're using Primer.css, you would just use the built-in column layouts.

To get the line heights to match you'll notice that the `<h3>` has additional margins on it. So just size your button element to have similar margins. Below you'll see that's what I did with the class `.h3-size`.

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="one-fifth column center-text">
      <a href="#" class="btn primary h3-size">My Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="four-fifths column ">
      <h3>My H3 heading</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.h3-size {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
```